# XPATH: Who is the player who has scored the most points in a match?

Tags: xml, xpath

I've a XML and I need  the player who has scored the most points in a match in xpath.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <match>
        <summary>
            <team name="Barça" score="7">
                <scorecard>
                    <name points="1">Iniesta</name>
                    <name points="2">Suarez</name>
                    <name points="4">Messi</name>
                </scorecard>
            </team>
            <team name="Madrid" score="26">
                <scorecard>
                      <name points="3">Ronaldo</name>
                      <name points="1">Buitre</name>
                      <name points="2">Bale</name>
                </scorecard>
            </team>
        </summary>
    </match>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/match/summary/team/scorecard/name[
    not(@points < /match/summary/team/scorecard/name/@points)
]/text()
```

Meaning: find a player such that there's no points anywhere greater than his.

Tested with

```
xmllint -xpath '/match/summary/team/scorecard/name[not(@points < /match/summary/team/scorecard/name/@points)]/text()' ~/file.xml
```

Comment: Unless your XPath processor has quite a smart optimizer, this will have quadratic performance.

Comment: @dontknow: That's exactly what this XPath expression returns. Have you tried it? How was the output different to your expectations?

Answer (score 0):

@choroba's answer is just fine. XPath 2.0 solution :

```
 //name[@points=max(//name/@points)]/text()
```

Output : Messi

EDIT : distinct-value removed. Thx to @Michael Kay.

Comment: `max(distinct-values(X))` is the same as `max(X)` and I very much doubt that the redundant call on `distinct-values()` helps performance.

Comment: Dully noted. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to have Saxon (PE or higher) then

```
saxon:highest(//name, function($team) { +$team!@points })
```

should be the fastest solution.